# subprocess.call path problem , how to fix?

Tags: python, subprocess

my subprocess.call problem is that  my shortcut target is with extra INI file which is LIV2.INI and my exe file should run whit it . and my target link in shortcut looks like this

```py
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AMO\EXE\PROGRAM LIVE 2.exe" LIV2.INI
```

i tried this

```py
subprocess.call('"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\PROGRAM LIVE 2.exe" LIV2.INI')
```

and i tried this

```py
subprocess.call('C:\Users\admin\Desktop\PROGRAM LIVE 2.exe LIV2.INI')
```

and i still get error that the ini file missing ? How can i fix this :)

THank you in advance

ERROR : INI FILE Missing or Wrong Name

Comment: `subprocess.call` expects a list as a argument, not a string. Fix that first

Comment: look up "raw strings" and "escape characters"

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please also edit your question to actually include the error since you will get a syntax error, not an error that the ini file is missing.

You have two issues here, first you have a syntax error since `"\Us"` is not a valid string in python. `\u` marks the start of a Unicode escape sequence and the character S is not a valid unicode escape key. You can fix this by using double `\\`  to escape the `\`  character and tell python you want your string to include a `\`  and not use it as the start of a escape sequence.

Secondly, `subprocess.call` excpects a list, not a string (unless you set `shell=True`; but don't do that, since it means you have to manually escape things which you have already discovered is hard). The first element of the list
is the executable to run and the rest are command line arguments. For example if you wanted to run `python`eand print "hello world" you would type:

```
subprocess.call(['python', '-c', 'print ("hello world")'])
```

Notice the missing quotes around the python string? You don't need those since the command line arguments are passed in raw and no shell will attempt to split them if you don't include quotes.

Putting it all together creates something like this:

```
subprocess.call(['C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\PROGRAM LIVE 2.exe', 'LIV2.INI'])
```

Notice the double backslashes and how each command line argument is its own list element.